# Applying a certain effect to input[type=submit]

Tags: html, css, forms, input, submit

I'm using a CSS hover effect on buttons and menu-links. The links work fine because they are anchor tags, while the buttons do not work since they are used in forms as input[type=submit].

The HTML:

```
<div class="submit">
      <span data-hover="Send">
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
      </span>
</div>
```

The .submit-wrapper class is used for decoration (as seen in the CSS below), while the span applies the actual hover effect.

The CSS:

```
.submit /* Need this to hide the second text -- otherwise it will show beneath */ {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.submit > span {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.submit > span::before /* The effect in place */ {
    padding-top: 49px;
    content: attr(data-hover);
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    left: 28px;
    top: 0;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}

.submit:hover > span, .submit:focus > span /* The actual effect on hover */ {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

Here's the problem: I cannot click on the button. It shows the default cursor and completely ignores the fact that it's a button (an input submit type). So I have two questions:

**1. Is it possible to use an anchor tag instead of an input type="submit"?**

**2. If not, how do I make the input type="submit" clickable?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, when I put that into jsfiddle, I can't click the button because your translate is moving it offscreen. When I remove that I can click the button just fine.

Otherwise, you can use a link that has jQuery attached to it so when it's clicked, submit the form. see http://api.jquery.com/submit/